# NoMethodError in Contacts#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following a tutorial from "Coder Manual" and am trying to create a contact form. It seems like I have everything in place but it will not work.

contacts_controller

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
  end
end


class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email
      t.text :comments
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

this is the **new.html.erb**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <div class="well">
      <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :name %>
          <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :email %>
          <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.label :comments %>
          <%= f.text_area :comments, class: 'form-control' %>
        </div>
        <%= f.submit 'Submit', class: 'btn btn-default' %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am getting the `NoMethodError in Contacts#new`

Stack trace

```
activemodel (4.1.0) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:206:in `method_missing'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/base.rb:28:in `value'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/base.rb:37:in `value_before_type_cast'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/text_field.rb:9:in `block in render'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/text_field.rb:9:in `fetch'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/helpers/tags/text_field.rb:9:in `render'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:771:in `text_field'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:1258:in `text_field'
app/views/contacts/new.html.erb:4:in `block in _app_views_contacts_new_html_erb__916588012054069058_69974500316060'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `block in capture'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:200:in `with_output_buffer'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/helpers/capture_helper.rb:38:in `capture'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:434:in `form_for'
app/views/contacts/new.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_contacts_new_html_erb__916588012054069058_69974500316060'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:55:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:62:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:17:in `render'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:99:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:82:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
actionview (4.1.0) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
activerecord (4.1.0) lib/active_record/migration.rb:380:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.0) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/home/action/.parts/packages/ruby2.1/2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: can you show your `contacts_controller.rb` controller?

Comment: class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end
  
  def create
  end
end

Comment: so can you explain why youre `create` method is empty? you need to ask Rails to actually CREATE a new contact. The form you have there, when submitted will need to use the `create`  method to make a new entry into your databse.

Comment: sorry im not sure how to format the sample in my response, this is my first time here.

Comment: The tutorial didn't add anything to the {create} method yet. I am following it as i go and ran into this.

Comment: Please add the compete stack trace

Comment: You will get that Error if you have empty the new method. And you have this: @contact = Contact.new. That is correct. So dont make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works...

`<%= form_for Contact.new do |f| %>`

However, please add your `contacts_controller.rb` code. I have a feeling you didn't specify your `new`, `show` and `create` actions there.

Comment: Just a note that this prevents reuse of the form template for editing.

Comment: That is absolutely true. However, this is as far as help can go without seeing the controller file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your controller code `create`action. The new action won't create a new record. You need to write that logic in create action. Change your code controller code to this. And try.

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end

  def create
   @contact = Contact.build(contact_params)
  end
end

# define your contact params here

private

 def contact_params
   params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :comments)
 end
```

Answer (score -1):

In your new.html.erb.
change the

```
<%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
```

to

```
<%= form_for "contacts" do |f| %>
```

That seems to solve the problem for me...